# Почему не записывается минимальный элемент?

Tags: c++

В выводе дает мусорное значение.

```
// Runtime.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    const int arraySize = 200000;
    int array[arraySize];
    int counter = 0;
    int min = array[0];
    for (counter; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        array[arraySize] = rand() % 50 - rand() % 50;
        std::cout << array[arraySize] << " ";
    
    }

    for (counter = 1; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] < min)
            min = array[counter]; // почему не минимальный элемент?
    }

    std::cout << "\nmin: " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nruntime: " << clock() / 1000.0 << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в массиве изначально ничего не записывается

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    const int arraySize = 200000;
    int array[arraySize];
    int counter = 0;
    int min = array[0];
    for (counter; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        array[arraySize] = rand() % 50 - rand() % 50; // !!! ВЫХОД ЗА ГРАНИЦЫ МАССИВА
        std::cout << array[arraySize] << " "; // !!! ВЫХОД ЗА ГРАНИЦЫ МАССИВА
    
    }

    for (counter = 1; counter < arraySize; counter++)
    {
        if (array[counter] < min)
            min = array[counter]; // почему не минимальный элемент?
    }

    std::cout << "\nmin: " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nruntime: " << clock() / 1000.0 << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если ответ вас устроил - здесь принято такие ответы принимать (птичка слева). Вы бы, кстати, об этом знали, если бы прочли хотя бы вводную страницу сайта - чего вы не сделали...